# Why do I have to declare <?php

Tags: php

I think that I've been used to a fairly liberal policy regarding the PHP declaration in projects - I've always just used:

```
<? // here is my php code ?>
```

I just setup an nginx server using PHP-FPM under FastCGI and now it requires me to declare explicitly:

```
<?php // here is my php code ?>
```

Is there any way to change that? (Since otherwise I would have to go into my project and find/replace all of the instances where this occurs).

Comment: [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), though it isn't recommended to use...

Comment: @Michael, from 5.4 version is always enabled. So yes, it's recommended to use it.

Comment: @drgomesp Incorrect - with 5.4, the output shorthand `<?=` is always available, while `short_open_tag` is off by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to enable [short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) via the php.ini configuration file. However, if you are using XML concurrently with PHP, there will be a conflict.

Just found a [good article](http://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2009/06/maximum-failure-php-6-deprecates-short.html) on the deprecation of short tags in PHP6.

Comment: I would add the caviate that PHP, in the newer versions, is doing away with short tags. So you will have to use the <?php ?> tag. Whether you like it or not. Also it really isn't hard to do, so why are you complaining?

Comment: It's not that it's hard to do, but it's annoying to migrate a legacy project where short open tags were used in favor of the proper declarative.

Comment: seriously ? If I were you, I would just open all those files in a code text editor (like notepad++) and replace all `<?` with `<?php`. It takes about 2 minutes...

Answer (score 5):

Go into php.ini and find the option `short_open_tag`. Set it to `On`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

[Short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files that have PHP code blocks embedded in them. You **MUST** start a php code block with `<?php` (or `<?` if you've got short-tags enabled). There is no way around this. Without that opening tag, the PHP interpreter will just act as a very expensive version of 'cat'.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers given are correct in how to enable short tags, I would recommend against it.  Consider that the code you write may not be run solely on your computer.  If you plan on distributing your code or deploying it to a production server you should always use `<?php` to open the tags as this will minimize the likelihood of your code not running and the troubleshooting associated with it.